# bibtex author field: multiple spellings

Tags: bibtex

I have an author who has a cryllic spelling and a romanized spelling. Thus, I'd like him to be listed in the bibliography as:

Alexander Pushkin (Алекса́ндр Пу́шкин).

However, hacking around with the bibtex author field I haven't found a native way to do it yet. Is there one?

Answer (score 3):

You could double brace the author field:

```
author = {{Alexander Pushkin (Алексáндр Пýшкин)}}
```

By doing so, however, BibTeX cannot split the name in firstname and lastname.

Comment: And I guess citations of the form [Pus98] won't work either.. :\

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create your own BST, that will understand a `nativeauthor` field (or maybe you can think of a different name).

Advantage: you can make the formatting be just as you like it.

Disadvantage 1: standard bibliography styles will ignore the `nativeauthor` field and behave as though it were absent.

Disadvantage 2: you will need to learn the somewhat arcane style definition language used by bibtex (it's a stack language, so if you are familiar with writing postscript by hand, then you won't find it too hard...)